# Codeigniter trying to get a specific URL pattern

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-routing

I have two models called Lessons and Parts. Every lesson has many parts. I'm new to MVC and to Codeigniter but the desired URL is this:

> `example.com/lesson/2/part/3`

I assume I'm supposed to do this with rewrite rules in either the .htaccess or the routes. I need help to get this right and an explanation of the rewrite rule or the route would be perfect.

Maybe Part is actually a method of the lesson's controller?

Answer (score 0):

[The CodeIgniter User Guide has a useful page on URI Routing.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

You can do something like this to change it so that `part` is a method in the `lesson` controller:

`$route['lesson/(:num)/part/(:num)'] = "lesson/part/$1/$2";`

The guide is somewhat inconsistent in its inclusion of the brackets, so if that doesn't work then try this instead:

`$route['lesson/:num/part/:num'] = "lesson/part/$1/$2";`

Comment: The brackets() are used for grouping $1, $2 etc

Comment: I don't know if part being a method of lesson respect MVC